# Why do I get "wrong version error" when I add SSl to the Indy Zip Code Lookup example in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I thought I would try something simple to try to understand Web client/server applications since I know nothing about it but I need to learn. I downloaded the "Zip Code look up" example from the web (both client and server). Compiled them and everything worked as advertised.

Then I dropped an SSL IO Handler on each form and specified them as the handlers with "sslvTLSv1" selected in both. Now it doesn't work. Every time I try to look up zip codes in the client app, I get, "error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number." I uninstalled the original Indy library and installed the latest version (10.6.2.5264). Just to be sure, I got the most recent SSL libraries and put them in both program folders.

I have looked at numerous questions and answers about SSL in Indy and it seems like it should work. What am I missing?

**This is the relevant section from the Server DFM:**

```
object IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer
  Active = True
  Bindings = <
    item
      IP = '127.0.0.1'
      Port = 6000
    end>
  DefaultPort = 6000
  IOHandler = Handler
  OnConnect = IdTCPServer1Connect
  OnExecute = IdTCPServer1Execute
  Left = 32
  Top = 24
end
object Handler: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL
  SSLOptions.Mode = sslmServer
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
  Left = 100
  Top = 32
end
```

**And this is the relevant section of the Client DFM.**

```
object Client: TIdTCPClient
  IOHandler = Handler
  ConnectTimeout = 0
  Host = '127.0.0.1'
  IPVersion = Id_IPv4
  Port = 6000
  ReadTimeout = -1
  Left = 209
  Top = 16
end
object Handler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
  Destination = '127.0.0.1:6000'
  Host = '127.0.0.1'
  MaxLineAction = maException
  Port = 6000
  DefaultPort = 0
  SSLOptions.Mode = sslmClient
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
  Left = 296
  Top = 32
end
```

### After trying Remy's suggestion

I added code to set the PassThrough to false and now I get a different error.
"error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure."

For those who want to look at the source code, it is on the web at http://www.atozedsoftware.com/indy/demos/10/index.EN.aspx (I'm using the OnExecute version of the server). The only difference now being the line in each unit setting the PassThrough mode.

**In the sever code:**

```
procedure TformMain.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('200 Zip Code Server Ready.');
  AContext.Data := TUserData.Create;
end;
```

**In the client code:**

```
procedure TformMain.butnLookupClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  butnLookup.Enabled := False; try
    lboxResults.Clear;
    Handler.PassThrough := False;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show any of your code, only your DFMs. That is not enough. But I suspect what is *likely* happening is that you are setting the `IOHandler.PassThrough` property to false on the client side, but are not doing the same on the server side.

When a client connects to `TIdTCPServer`, SSL/TLS is not activated by the server by default so the server can analyze the client, maybe even communicate unsecurely with it, before deciding whether SSL/TLS is needed.  This is to facilitate the server listening on multiple ports where not all ports use SSL/TLS at all (think HTTP vs HTTPS), and to handle `STARTTLS`-based protocols.

So, if you are not already doing so, make sure to set the `IOHandler.PassThrough` to false on both ends of the connection, eg:

```
Handler.PassThrough := False;
IdTCPClient1.Connect;
```

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
end;
```

If you are indeed doing so on both ends, but are still getting the same error, than make sure the `IOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLMethod`/`IOHandler.SSLOptions.TLSVersions` property really is configured correctly on both ends and they are using compatible settings.  You say you are using TLSv1 on both ends, so you should not be getting the error unless the server is really not using TLSv1.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped but now I get a different error. "error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure." It says ssl3 but only tlsv1 is selected in both components.

Comment: TLSv1 is based on SSLv3, that is why you see `ssl3` in OpenSSL error messages for TLSv1. In any case, the alert failure means that SSL/TLS is now being activated on each end (good) but the handshake is failing and the failing party is sending an SSL/TLS error message back to the other party to indicate why it failed (is it the client or server that is receiving the alert?). You are showing an OpenSSL error message, but what exception/error is Indy raising in reply to that?  What does the content of the alert failure itself actually say (use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to get that)?

Comment: If I had to guess, both parties are likely detecting TLSv1 in use but are not able to agree on a common set of encryption settings for it, so the communication cannot proceed.  You might need to provide a security certificate on both ends so they can configure their TLS ciphers accordingly.

Comment: The Delphi error is, "exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL." followed by the above SSL error info. And the error is reported by the client side.

Comment: That exception means OpenSSL's `SSL_connect()` function failed, in this case because the handshake failed on the server side and it alerted the client. The client handshake likely did not include something the server needed to complete the handshake. Are you getting an exception on the server side? Check the server's `OnException` event, or wrap the `PassThrough` assignment with a `try/except` (and re-raise it so the server sees it).

Comment: Yes the server does generate an error on the Pass Through assignment. "EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error accepting connection with SSL. error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher'".
How can that be when they are both running on the same PC?
Just for fun I tried with all three levels of TLS enabled but no luck.

Comment: "*no shared cipher*" - there you go then.  The client and server are not able to agree on a common encryption cipher that they both support, so they are not able to talk to each other.  Have a look at the `IOHandler.SSLOptions.CipherList` property. If blank, Indy uses `'AES:ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:+RC4:@STRENGTH'` (see the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT) for full syntax). But which ciphers are actually enabled depends on the settings used when the OpenSSL DLLs were compiled.  Are you using the EXACT SAME DLLs on both client and server?

Comment: If you are still getting the same error after making sure the client and server are using the same DLLs with the same ciphers enabled, then you will likely have to install an SSL certificate into your server, at least (see the `IOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile`, `RootCertFile`, and `KeyFile` properties). You can use OpenSSL's command-line tools to create a self-signed certificate for testing purposes until you are able (and willing) to purchase a real certificate (there are cheap options available).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have a TIdHTTP/TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL application which makes calls to a Google API (Analytics).  I make about 35,000 calls per day.  But about 30-50 times per day I get the "SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number" error.  Is there anything that can explain this?  I don't think it is a source code issue.  Because I can make the same call again and it works.  Seems arbitrary.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MSchenkel: Without seeing your code or the HTTP(S) requests on the wire, I can only guess. Maybe some of the requests are being redirected to URLs that do not match your SSLIOHandler's settings.  Either way, this belongs as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end I had to do a little bit more than drop a couple of controls on the form.

First I had to add code to set the PassThrough property for each of the SSL controls to false (maybe they should be published properties?).

Then I had to install a valid certificate and set the CertFile, KeyFile and RootCertFile properties on the server side.

Now it works!

Thanks to Remy for his help and, BTW this was using OpenSSL v1.0.2 and Indy 10.5.5. in Win32 (Vista) with Delphi 2010.